# CSS Animation, State change finish animation

Tags: css, ajax, animation

We are implementing a wishlist functionality on a site we are developing, and when the user clicks on an icon to add the current item to a wishlist, it fires an ajax request.

Now while that ajax request is doing it's business, we add a loading class to the icon, so it scales bigger and smaller slightly. My issue, is once the ajax request has finished loading, we then remove that class, but the animation abruptly stops rather than scaling back down to it's initial size.

How can we make the animation finish, rather than just suddenly stopping?

Below is my CSS:

```
/**
 * Keyframes
 */
@keyframes breathe {

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}



/**
 * Icon
 */
.wishlist-icn {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

    .wishlist-icn--isAdded {
        fill: #4B3814;
    }

    .wishlist-icn--isLoading {
        animation: breathe 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal both;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Try applying [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp)

The normal behavior after CSS animation is done is that it resets the styles to the initial state. The way I see the process here is that when you remove the `--isLoading` class the animation stops and reverts the styles to the original state. Only after then the transitions starts to work and has nothing to do since the styles already are reset. `animation-fill-mode: forwards` in `.wishlist-icn` would prevent the animation from resetting, thus the transition would be able to operate gradually. To be sure you can add `transform: scale(1)` to `.wishlist-icn` or to `:not(.wishlist-icn--isLoading)` so that the transition knew what to head for. Not that I have tested it in this particular case, but it's worth trying ;P

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.start-animation').on('click', function() {
  $('.wishlist-icn').addClass('wishlist-icn--isLoading');
});



$('.stop-animation').on('click', function() {
  $(".wishlist-icn").bind("mozAnimationIteration animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("wishlist-icn--isLoading");
  });
});
```

```css
/**
 * Keyframes
 */

@keyframes breathe {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
/**
 * Icon
 */

.wishlist-icn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.wishlist-icn--isAdded {
  fill: #4B3814;
}
.wishlist-icn--isLoading {
  animation: breathe 2s ease-in-out 0s infinite normal both;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
}
.wishlist-icn--isLoaded {
  transform: scale(1);
}
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wishlist-icn"> <i class="ion-heart"></i>

</div>
<button class="start-animation">start animation</button>
<button class="stop-animation">stop animation</button>
```

you would probably have to use javascript to listen for the animation iteration to end then remove the class.

```
$(".wishlist-icn").bind( "mozAnimationIteration animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration" , function() {
      $(this).removeClass("wishlist-icn--isLoading");
});
```